# Contract Design: Interfaces

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Why use interfaces? I've heard this allows for easier bug fixes down the road, but with or without an interface, wouldn't you have have to scrap the bugged contract entirely?

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are a good way to let people understand how to use a contract.

On a purely utilitarian view, if you keep your contracts into different files, interfaces allow you to avoid cross-reference compilation errors:

`I.sol`:

```
contract I {
    function deployB();
    function doSomething();
}
```

`J.sol`:

```
contract J {
    function doOnI(address i);
}
```

`A.sol`:

```
import "J.sol";
import "B.sol";
contract A is I {
    function deployB() {
        new B();
    }
    function doSomething() {}
}
```

`B.sol`:

```
import "I.sol";
import "J.sol";
// You would not be able to import A.
contract B is J {
    function doOnI(address i) {
        I(i).doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: So if "A" creates a contract "B" which wants to use a function defined in "A", contract "B" must use the interface of  "A"?

Comment: Yes, that is always true as the Solidity compiler will replace `A`'s function calls with their equivalent in bytecode. However, here, because of the `import` cyclicality, we need to use interfaces.

Comment: Ok great, so there is no security benefit to using interfaces?

Comment: Not that I know of. After all, a Solidity contract is compiled into bytecode, which has no concept of interface. If your bytecode is there and can be called, it does not matter whether you used interfaces.